# Displaying a view in the middle of an MVC3 controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to flash a view multiple times within a controller.

```
public ActionResult MyController()
{
    ViewBag.Data=CalculateSomeData();
    ShowView();
    ViewBag.Data+=CalculateMoreData();
    ShowView();
    ViewBag.Data+=CalculateExtraData();
    return View();
}
```

It takes a long time to calculate the data and I would like to display the view in increments.

Comment: Your action has to return an ActionResult, and it happens in that `return View();` line. Nothing gets returned before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a job for a bit of ajax and some rethinking about how your job will run.

first things first show your view I would put this in its own controller where the User can request Tasks

```
public class RequestTaskController: Controller
{
   public ActionResult LongRunningAction()
   {
       return View();
   }
}
```

Next I would create another Controller to do the work with methods that add the task and returns a partial result

```
public class WorkController: Controller
{
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult CreateLongRunningTask(TaskRequestViewModel viewModel)
   {
       AddTask(viewModel);
       return CurrentTasks();
   }
}


public PartialViewResult AddTask(TaskRequestViewModel viewModel)
{
   // I'm using Session here because its easy
    var currentTasks = Session["tasks"] as ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task>??
                              new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task>();

    Task task;
    if (!currentTasks.TryGetValue(viewModel.Key, out task))
    {
       task = new Task(); // what ever that is
       currentTasks.TryAdd(key, task);
    }

    // do stuff with task like change progess, add payload, mark as complete

}



public PartialViewResult CurrentTasks()
{
     ViewData.Model = Session["tasks"] as ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task>??
                              new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task>();

    // do stuff with task like change progess, add payload, mark as complete

     return PartialView("_CurrentTasks");
}
```

the partial View _CurrentTasks.cshtml would be in Views/Shared and would list what tasks you have and what progress they are up to.

```
 @using System.Collections.Concurrent
 @using Your.Models
 @model ConcurrentDictionary<string, Tasks>

<ul>
@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
   foreach (var task in Model)
    {
       <li>@:task</li>
    }
}
</ul>
```

So that will take care of displaying them. now you want your LongRunningAction view to wrap it all up so somewhere on there you are going to want to do something like this.

```
<div id="currentTasks" />

<script type="text/javascript">

var interval;

function loadPartialView() {
    //Populate the contents of the placeholder with the result returned by the action method 
    $('#currentTasks').load('@Url.Action("CurrentTasks", "Work")', function () {
        // maybe do something to links
    });
}

$(function () {

    loadPartialView();

    interval = setInterval(loadPartialView, 5000);

});

</script>
```

Hopefully that gets you to where you want to be.

Comment: WOW. What an amazing answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like that. Nothing is sent to the browser until the view is rendered, and that happens after you return the view from the controller.

If you want the page to be displayed while you calculate the data, you have to do it in two or more requests. First display the plain page without the data, then make AJAX requests to the server where you calculate the data and return to the script to be displayed in the page.